# Using XML Attributes as list source in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, xaml, data-binding

I need to be able to use a series of attributes as the source in a WPF list view. I'm currently stuck on how to do this. I know how to do it for XML nodes but not for attributes. Here's an example of what I'm trying to bind too:

```
<Stats HP="55000" MP="2500" SP="2500" Strength="212" Vitality="125" Magic="200" Spirit="162" Skill="111" Speed="109" Evasion="100" MgEvasion="100" Accuracy="100" Luck="55" />
```

I want each stat name/value to be an entry in the listview. Here's the code I've been trying to make work:

```
<TabControl.DataContext>
     <Binding ElementName="EnemyLevelsListBox" Path="SelectedItem"/>
</TabControl.DataContext>
<TabItem Header="Stats" Name="EnemyStatsTab">
      <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Stats}" Height="310" Name="EnemyStatViewDisplay" Width="411" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Attribute.Name}" />
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Attribute.Value}" />
            </DataTemplate>
       </ListView.ItemTemplate>
       </ListView>
</TabItem>
```

The TabControl.DataContext binding exposes the parent XMLNode of the Stats element. I know this for certain as I'm using subnodes of the parent elsewhere and they work correctly. I don't know what to put for the ListView ItemsSource or for the DataTemplate's textblock binds. Does someone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `XPath` in the `ItemsSource` binding as you want to target the [`Attributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.attributes.aspx) collection on the [`XmlNode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.aspx) object. You should make sure you are already having the `Stats` element as `DataContext`, then set the `Path` to `Attributes`:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Attributes}" DataContext="<bind to stats element if necessary>">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Stat" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Value" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just bind the listview to the attributes?

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WPF1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="350">

    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <local:AttributesToEnumerableConverter x:Key="AttributesToEnumerableConverter" />
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Stats, Converter={StaticResource AttributesToEnumerableConverter}}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="5" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value}" Margin="5" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace WPF1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = this;
        }

        public XElement Stats
        {
            get { return XElement.Parse("<Stats HP=\"55000\" MP=\"2500\" SP=\"2500\" Strength=\"212\" Vitality=\"125\" Magic=\"200\" Spirit=\"162\" Skill=\"111\" Speed=\"109\" Evasion=\"100\" MgEvasion=\"100\" Accuracy=\"100\" Luck=\"55\" />"); }
        }
    }

    public class AttributesToEnumerableConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (value as XElement).Attributes(); 
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```